# WSO2 Problems to access on port 8082

Tags: java, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

- I tried to call my rest service with WSO2.

  - I use wso version 5.0.0. Java 1.8. Eclipse Mars2.
  - I followed the url : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

1) I define my rest service:
MyRestNode.png
[image: My rest services on Node]

2) I created my service on eclipse studio dev tools:
[image: Eclise StudioDevTools]

3) I Deploy to wso2, my EndPoint:
[image: EndPoint on Eclipse]

4) API
[image: API]

When I call curl on terminal: 
    curl -v -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://192.168.10.178:8280/mapa/1/101

Shows the message:

> Trying 192.168.10.178...

```
> Connected to 192.168.10.178 (192.168.10.178) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /mapa/1/101 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.10.178:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 12:38:51 GMT
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection #0 to host 192.168.10.178 left intact
```

5) API XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mapa" name="MapaServicesAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/mapa/{codigoAgenteCampo}/{codigoMunicipio}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Teste com o mapa services node&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="MapaRestEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

6) Endpoint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="MapaRestEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8000/rest/rotas/completa/{codigoAgenteCampo}/{codigoMunicipio}"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: please, share your API xml definition.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I share endpoint and API xml, itens 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

****************************UPDATE: ****************************************

correct endpoint configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="MapaRestEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8000/rest/rotas/completa/{uri.var.codigoAgenteCampo}/{uri.var.codigoMunicipio}"/>
</endpoint>
```

****************************END UPDATE************************************

The URL you need to call is api context + uri template. In this case:

http://localhost:8280/mapa/mapa/1/101

In my scenario I mock the backend json response with soapui.

My proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mapa" name="MapaServicesAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/mapa/{codigoAgenteCampo}/{codigoMunicipio}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Teste com o mapa services node&quot;"/>
                <property name="codigoAgenteCampo" expression="get-property('uri.var.codigoAgenteCampo')"/>
                <property name="codigoMunicipio" expression="get-property('uri.var.codigoMunicipio')"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="MapaRestEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

The endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="MapaRestEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8000/rest/rotas/completa/{uri.var.codigoAgenteCampo}/{uri.var.codigoMunicipio}"/>
</endpoint>
```

The curl response:

```
D:\integ\wso2am-2.0.0\bin>curl -v -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8283/mapa/mapa/1/101
* About to connect() to localhost port 8283 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8283 (#0)
> GET /mapa/mapa/1/101 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8u zlib/1.2.6 libssh2/1.4.0
> Host: localhost:8283
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 05:50:45 GMT
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 05:50:45 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<
{
        data:[
{
"id":1
},
{
"id":2
}
]
        }* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

And the wso2 ESB log:

```
[2017-01-31 00:50:45,409]  INFO - LogMediator message = "Teste com o mapa services node", codigoAgenteCampo = 1, codigoMunicipio = 101
[2017-01-31 00:50:45,421]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:56597c92-d5fe-4003-b25a-d11b60dd28df, Di
rection: response, Payload: {
        data:[
{
"id":1
},
{
"id":2
}
]
        }
```

Comment: I post the another error, but stays above your answer. 
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'C' (code 67) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]

Comment: ok, one step after another, this new error is another issue with your config...the first issue was fixed...can you check the backend response?

Comment: It works ok. I call curl -v -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8000/rest/rotas/completa/1/101, return HTTP/1.1 200 OK response:{"data":[{"id":1,"codigo":101,"limite":"Ponte do Jandiá 1 até os ramais da margem do rio Amazonas, margem esquerda rodovia Trancredo Neves","descricao":"Rota25","codigoIBGE":1600303,"municipio":"Macapá","totalArea":580,"totalAreaTrabalhada":145,"hospedesCadastrados":2580,"hospedesContabilizados":6145,"armadilhaMcphail":30,"armadilhaJackson":15,"codigoAgenteCampo":1,"idMunicipio":101}]}

Comment: using the same proxy I configure my backend with your response and it work just fine...

Comment: It is very strange. Every sample that I test give me some error. Can you share your project on github or another local that I get the same and test on my environment, please.

Comment: In my response you have the proxy, the endpoint and for the backend  I used soapui with the same response that you provided me. can you expose your BE in internet for testing?

Comment: BE means backend ? 
My backend is  a simple node server, I mock the real services that not exist yet. Yes I can put on my github and I will pass for you.

Comment: When run npm install give me some errors: 160 error 404 'types' is not in the npm registry.
160 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it
160 error 404
160 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
160 error 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
161 error System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
162 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
163 error cwd /opt/repo/backend-wso2
164 error node -v v0.10.25
165 error npm -v 1.3.10
166 error code E404

Comment: you need to install recently version of node. At the README I put the version of node:
Node Version: v6.7.0 and NPM Version: v3.10.3

The idea is to install nvm. NVM manages versions of node:
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

To install or update nvm, you can use the install script using cURL:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
or Wget:

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash

After this: nvm install v6.7.0 it will install my version of node and npm.

Comment: ok, the last jeje. take a look to my endpoint again, in every parameter you past in the http-endpoint, you must specify at the beginning the string uri.var., I  try and it work with your backend.

Comment: So, in my server I will put :
app.get('/rest/rotas/completa/:uri.var.codigoAgenteCampo/:uri.var.municipio', function(req, res, next) {
    responder(res, getRotasDetalhadaPorAgente(req.params));
});

I will try then I will return feedback. The project is in my home. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in you server not, in the endpoint xml config inside esb. take a look:
<endpoint name="MapaRestEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8200/rest/rotas/completa/{uri.var.codigoAgenteCampo}/{uri.var.codigoMunicipio}"/>
</endpoint>

Comment: Hi Jorge, I tried this. But gives me suspended: 
INFO - LogMediator message = "Teste com o mapa services node", codigoAgenteCampo = 1, codigoMunicipio = 101
EndpointContext Endpoint : TransporteFrutasEP with address http://localhost:8200/rest/rotas/completa/{uri.var.cod‌​igoAgenteCampo}/{uri‌​.var.codigoMunicipio‌​} will be marked **SUSPENDED** as it failed
- EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : TransporteFrutasEP with address http://localhost:8200/rest/rotas/completa/{uri.var.cod‌​igoAgenteCampo}/{uri‌​.var.codigoMunicipio‌​}

Comment: please, use the endpoint config in my response, inside comments the URL it´s broken. the right endpoint configuration it´s between my proxy configuration and the curl response.

Comment: Jorge, the url is broken only in comments. In project is ok, I think , now, it is a configuration problem, like timeout configuration, because on the log the values appear correct, the last message :WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-7 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:36037. I pull my all project developer studio on the same url in the folder wso2: https://github.com/alessandrots/backend-wso2. If you can see.

Comment: can I commit to your repo? I found that your url in endpoint xml config have a problem with some characters

Comment: Hi Jorge! I put your github user as collaborator on my repository. Feel free to make whatever modifications you feel you need.

Comment: endpoint modified. try now. problem with encoding and some characters in cod‌​igoAgenteCampo and codigoMunicipio

Comment: Super Jorge, it works!!!! Thanks a lot!!! Your help is the best! 
I've tried to punctuate your answer, but by the rules here, I'm not getting permission. In addition to the site documentation, would you suggest any other material that could give me a better insight into wso2? - Again, thanks, best Regards, Alessandro!!!

Comment: well, just check my answer as the right one :-D

http://desarrollosoa.blogspot.com/

https://www.yenlo.com/blog

web.chakray.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks! I will see both! Hasta la vista!